# Button click via id not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Almost all click functions on my website doesn't work. Last few days, it was working, but now it won't.

Sample would be:

**index.php (inside the `<head>`)**

```
<link href="/theme/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/theme/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/theme/css/bootflat.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/theme/css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/theme/admin/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/theme/css/dataurl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="/theme/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/theme/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/theme/js/site.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/theme/js/moment.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/theme/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/fa905179b0.js"></script>
<script src="/theme/js/SmoothScroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/theme/js/pace.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**the button**

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="save-new">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

**after the `</body>`**

```
<link href="/theme/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="/theme/js/bootstrap-notify.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/theme/js/jquery.fs.selecter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/staff/main/js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function viewPeriods() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                type: "view"
            },
            url: "/staff/main/ajax/marking-periods.php",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#periods").hide().html(data).fadeIn();
            }
        });
    }

    $("#save-new").click(function() {
        var title = $("#title").val();
        var start = $("#start").val();
        var end = $("#end").val();
        var gstart = $("#gstart").val();
        var gend = $("#gend").val();
        var ptype = $("#type").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                title: title,
                start: start,
                end: end,
                gstart: gstart,
                gend: gend,
                ptype: ptype,
                type: "add"
            },
            url: "/staff/main/ajax/marking-periods.php",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                $.notify({
                    icon: data.icon,
                    title: data.title,
                    message: data.message 
                },
                {
                    element: 'body',
                    allow_dismiss: true,
                    newest_on_top: false,
                    type: data.status,
                    icon_type: 'class',
                    template: '<div data-notify="container" class="col-xs-11 col-sm-3 alert alert-{0}" role="alert">' +
                        '<button type="button" aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-notify="dismiss"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>' +
                        '<span data-notify="icon"></span> ' +
                        '<span data-notify="title">{1}</span> ' +
                        '<span data-notify="message">{2}</span>' +
                    '</div>' 
                });

                $("#new-period").modal("hide");

                viewPeriods();
            }
        });
    });

    viewPeriods();
});
```

No error in the console was found so I don't really know where I went wrong. The modal doesn't hide and nothing really happens after clicking the button. Other pages were like this as well, have worked before but now won't.

Comment: Just put an alert inside document.ready and check if jquery working fine?

Comment: use debugger statements, what happens? Since you are hiding the modal in the success method, my guess is the server is returning an error message... Add an error handler to your Ajax call.

Comment: go to your dev tools and see if the ajax is triggering

Comment: @MayankPandeyz I tried placing an alert inside document.ready and inside the click function and both doesn't work :-(

Comment: @devgirl, `script.js` should be included before `</body>` and not after it.

Comment: This happens in your local env or on server?

Comment: @epascarello, I did just now and nothing happens again.

Comment: So is the document.ready being called? Is the it finding the element? `console.log($("#save-new").length);`

Comment: @Yogesh, it worked. It worked a few days ago with it after the `</body>` tag. What could be the explanation why it didn't work now? :-\

Comment: You can try moving that inside `</body>` tag and see if that works.

Comment: @Yogesh, yes it did work. I was just wondering why did it work a few days ago with the script after `</body>` tag, but now it won't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **after the `</body>`**
>
> ```
> <link href="/theme/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
> <script src="/theme/js/bootstrap-notify.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
> <script src="/theme/js/jquery.fs.selecter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
> <script src="/staff/main/js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
> ```

You've added the `script.js` file at wrong position. It should be added before closing `</head>` or  tag and not after closing `</body>` tag. Your page HTML should look something like this.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="/theme/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="/theme/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="/theme/css/bootflat.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="/theme/css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="/theme/admin/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="/theme/css/dataurl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="/theme/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/theme/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/theme/js/site.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/theme/js/moment.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/theme/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/fa905179b0.js"></script>
    <script src="/theme/js/SmoothScroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/theme/js/pace.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="save-new">Submit</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    </div>
    <link href="/theme/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="/theme/js/bootstrap-notify.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/theme/js/jquery.fs.selecter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/staff/main/js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Although it really did work a few days ago with the `script.js` after the `</body>` tag, can't help wondering how it did.

Answer (score 2):

Delegate your click event:

```
$('body').on('click',"#save-new",function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

All references to external JavaScript files transfer to the bottom of the body tag. For example:
`<script src="/theme/js/bootstrap-notify.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/theme/js/jquery.fs.selecter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script></body>`